# How to query an ArcGIS Feature Service by attribute using Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geojson, json, feature-service

I have an ArcGIS Feature Server and what I have accomplished so far is this:

```
import json, requests

url = 'http://hebid.hessen.de/hlbk/hlbk_grundlagen/MapServer/1/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry={%22xmin%22:531435,%22ymin%22:5700831,%22xmax%22:543116,%22ymax%22:5716844,%22spatialReference%22:{%22wkid%22:25832}}&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=25832&outFields=*&outSR=25832'
resp = requests.get(url)
data = resp.json()
file_path = r'D:\testlayer.geojson'
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

This produces a perfect valid geojson (works with ArcMap and QGIS) using a given boundary-box, but I want to query this layer by attribute. According to this link https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/fsservicequery.html this should look something like this:

```
http://hebid.hessen.de/hlbk/hlbk_grundlagen/MapServer/query?layerDefs={"1":"OBJECTID=5256"}&returnGeometry=true&f=json
```

This does not give me my polygon as a geojson, but just the general information about the service itself. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: how do you install restapi... by pip or by conda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably have better luck doing the query against the layer itself.  This worked for me:

```
http://hebid.hessen.de/hlbk/hlbk_grundlagen/MapServer/1/query?where=OBJECTID=5256&returnGeometry=true&f=pjson&outFields=*
```

When using the query from a layer, you must include an `outFields` argument. Another thing to note, you will not be able to get the value as `geojson` from the service you referenced, as that is currently at version `10.2.2` and `geojson` as an output format was not added until `10.3`.  So unfortunately, you'll only be able to get esri json.  This is fairly easy to convert to geojson though.

Also, no need to reinvent the wheel.  There are existing packages available to work with ArcGIS REST Services such as [ArcREST](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST) or [restapi](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi).  I maintain the (horribly named) `restapi` package, but it is easy to use and here is how you can accomplish getting geojson:

```
import restapi

# sample to get geojson
url = 'https://services2.arcgis.com/ZkOsbg84o8DsPPaP/arcgis/rest/services/MN_Breweries/FeatureServer/0'
lyr = restapi.FeatureLayer(url) # can provide username, password, token, or proxy if secured

# get feature set as GeoJson, very important - must set outSR to 4326 for geojson
features = lyr.query(where="Name = 'Mankato Brewery'", outSR=4326, f='geojson')

# save geojson file
features.dump(r'C:\TEMP\Test.geojson', indent=2) # indent allows for pretty view

# OR, you can save it directly to a shapefile (does not require arcpy)
lyr.export_layer(r'C:\TEMP\test.shp', where="Name = 'Mankato Brewery'")
```

In the above example, I used a `restapi.FeatureLayer`, but there is also support for Map Service Layers via the `restapi.MapServiceLayer`.  Using your example:

```
lyr = restapi.MapServiceLayer('http://hebid.hessen.de/hlbk/hlbk_grundlagen/MapServer/1')

features = lyr.query(where='OBJECTID=5256')

features.dump(r'C:\TEMP\feature.json')
```

Comment: Wow, thx for this answer, works like a charm! My feature-server questions solved, now I have to start to deal with the map-server questions (with ogc wms/wfs everything seemed to be a little easier).

Comment: If you have `conda` and Python 3, you could `Python API for ArcGIS` (https://developers.arcgis.com/python/) that provides fairly Pythonic API into the `ArcGIS REST API`. `restapi` is awesome, but `Python API for ArcGIS` provides more options as it covers almost all capabilities of the `ArcGIS REST API`. You don't need ArcGIS software to be able to use this `conda` package.