# Get notification if feature service fails?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, error, web-service, feature-service

I have ArcGIS 10.7.1 feature services that occasionally fail/have errors.

The feature services are used to integrate/sync records to a separate work order management system. As such, the broken feature services can go unnoticed for some time, which is a problem.

Is there a way to get **notified** if feature services in a web service fail?

Comment: Only if you create a web app to test if the service returns results, and send an e-mail it it doesn't.

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/339846/135445

Comment: The process of writing a *daemon* process that wakes occasionally, invokes a few URLs, and sends mail if any services fail is more of a generic software engineering task, and would fit more naturally in [so] proper.

Comment: There are a wide variety of systems monitoring tools available (eg, https://www.zabbix.com/ ), including some online ones that you can subscribe to (eg https://anturis.com/ ).  They would be overkill if you don't need them for anything else, so you could just build your own if you only need to monitor one type of service, as suggested by @Eoin .

Answer (score 3):

You could write a Python script that periodically performs a simple query on ESRI REST API for these feature layers.

This thread should be useful for performing the query on the API from Python.
[How to query an ArcGIS Feature Service by attribute using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263191/how-to-query-an-arcgis-feature-service-by-attribute-using-python)

Then use smtplib to send yourself an email in the event that the query fails:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example

Finally, depending on the platform that you work with, use windows task scheduler or Linux/ mac crontab to periodically run the script.